# Toad 13.3.0.181 (32 bits) Connection Issue with oracle client 32 bit

Tags: toad

we have installed Toad 13.3 client Version in Windows 64 bit for oracle client 32 bit but trying to connect we are getting error "NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH does not specify TNSNAMES in the sqlnet.ora file".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLtyo.jpg)
Kindly suggest for this issue.

Comment: Have you tried the steps mentioned in the "Steps to take" in that error message?

Comment: Add this line to sqlnet.ora 'NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)'